# How to dockerize the cloudwatch agent and collectd to collect the metrics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to collect the custom metrics from my `ECS instances` and from the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/new-how-to-better-monitor-your-custom-application-metrics-using-amazon-cloudwatch-agent/) 
[image]

These are steps I need to follow

- Install [aws cloudwatch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/download-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html)
- Install [collectd](https://collectd.org/) daemon
- [Configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-custom-metrics-collectd.html) cloudwatch agent to get the metrics from collectd daemon

It seems I can

- Dockerize the cloudwatch agent (which seems to be [already done](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/cloudwatch-agent), but with lack of documentation)
- Dockerize collectd daemon

**Why to dockerize or not use awslogs driver for collecting metrics ?**

Currently we already have some `services` running as docker instances managed by `amazon ecs` and configured to use `awslog driver` to send logs to [amazon cloudwatch logs](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:cURL).

But in order to collect more custom metrics from the services e.g `number of requests per particular user from service a` the only solution which aws suggested is to use `colletd` with [curl plugin](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:cURL) along with `cloud watch agent`.

As due to some scaling issues, instead of running `cloudwatch agent` and `collectd` in a instance. I want to run those as containers.

**Question:**

Is there any way to run `cloudwatch agent in docker container` which can read the metrics from `collectd daemon` which runs in different container but on the same machine ?

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to run cloudwatch agent in your container, do not forget the rule of thumb, one process per container.

All you need to push application logs to stdout or stderr of the container and docker daemon will take care of it.

**Important Configuration:**

All you need to set log driver to AWS log driver in the task definition.

**Amazon CloudWatch Logs logging driver**

> The awslogs logging driver sends container logs to `Amazon CloudWatch
>   Logs`. Log entries can be retrieved through the AWS Management Console
>   or the AWS SDKs and Command Line Tools.

**Specifying a Log Configuration in your Task Definition**

> Before your containers can send logs to **CloudWatch**, you must
>   specify the awslogs log driver for containers in your task definition.
>   This section describes the log configuration for a container to use
>   the awslogs log driver. For more information, see Creating a Task
>   Definition.

```
   "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "awslogs-mysql",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "awslogs-example"
                }
            }
```

[image]

[AmazonECS-using_awslogs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html)

[image]

Comment: We currently use the same setup as you have explained, but i need to collect the custom metrics from other services running as docker containers

Comment: better to push custom metrics to stdout of container, you can filter from cloudwatch log based on tag. and I will never suggest to run agent inside container. better to use AWS sdk in your application and push custom metrics to cloudwatch using SDK.

Comment: Any specific reason on why not to use aws cloud watch agent in container as there seems to be 1M+ downloads from docker hub

Comment: Because of container nature, rule of thumb one process per container. Container should only run one process and container should be light weight. So for the sake of custom metrics better to push these with SDK instead of managing a agent inside container. You can run the agent if you want but my choice for logs and metrics is stdout