# How to run AWS CW Agent inside docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I've been trying to run the CW Agent inside the container but failed. 
error "unknown init system"

Im aware of docker logging driver but im trying to use the aws agent if possible.

Comment: As my exp, go with Fluentd if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS cloud watch agent docker, Here is offical docker image [amazon/cloudwatch-agent](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/cloudwatch-agent).

```
docker run -it --rm amazon/cloudwatch-agent
```

https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/cloudwatch-agent

**Building Your Own CloudWatch Agent Docker Image**

> You can build your own CloudWatch agent Docker image by referring to
>   the Dockerfile located at
>   https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudwatch-container-insights/blob/master/cloudwatch-agent-dockerfile/Dockerfile.

```
FROM debian:latest as build

RUN apt-get update &&  \
    apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -O https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/debian/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb && \
    dpkg -i -E amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb && \
    rm -rf /tmp/* && \
    rm -rf /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-config-wizard && \
    rm -rf /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl && \
    rm -rf /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config-downloader

FROM scratch

COPY --from=build /tmp /tmp

COPY --from=build /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

COPY --from=build /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent

ENV RUN_IN_CONTAINER="True"
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/start-amazon-cloudwatch-agent"]
```

[ContainerInsights-build-docker-image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContainerInsights-build-docker-image.html)

Comment: Cool! but how to connect this to other containers??

Comment: you can link other container with CW container. BTW better to push container logs directly to CW.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120860/how-to-dockerize-the-cloudwatch-agent-and-collectd-to-collect-the-metrics

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of Amazon ECS container agent.

> The Amazon ECS container agent allows container instances to connect
>   to your cluster. The Amazon ECS container agent is included in the
>   Amazon ECS-optimized AMIs, but you can also install it on any Amazon
>   EC2 instance that supports the Amazon ECS specification. The Amazon
>   ECS container agent is only supported on Amazon EC2 instances.

[Installing the Amazon ECS Container Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-install.html)

Make sure that the ec2 instance has the IAM role that allow access to ECS before you run the init command

Comment: does this work even though im not using the ECS service??